# symfony 5.2 Can't send smtp emails via MAILER : Expected response code "250"

Tags: email, smtp, symfony5

I am trying to send mails via smtp on my website, ( **Symfony 5.2** ), but every time I try to use **the built-in mailer bundle**, I get the error :

`Expected response code "250" but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required".`

I've tried sending mails using a **php script**, with the same smtp configuration, and **it works** everytime.

In my .env file :

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://mail.infomaniak.com:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=MY_USER_NAME&password=MY_PASSWORD
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#transport-setup, the mailer dsn format should be.

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:port
```

And not

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://mail.infomaniak.com:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=user&password=pass
```

Notice how the user and password are specified. Might also worth mentioning that you might need to URL encode your password should it contain characters that need such an encoding.

Have you tried the format from the docs?

Comment: Thanks a lot, cant believe I didn't see that!